# A continuous injection has a continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous injection. Then, the inverse $f^{-1}: f(I) \to I$ is continuous.

---

Proof Attempt:

Since $f^{-1}$ is an injection and $f: I \to f(I)$ is a surjection, $f: I \to f(I)$ is a bijection and so $f^{-1}: f(I) \to I$ exists.

Let $x_0 \in I$. We want to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(x_0)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, we need to show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that:

$$|y-f(x_0)| < \delta \implies |f^{-1}(y)-x_0| < \epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given so that $A = (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \subseteq I$. The same argument works for any larger $\epsilon$ because we can always just reuse the same $\delta$ that we find here. Then, $f(A)$ is an interval and since $f$ is injective, it is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Without loss of generality, let it be strictly increasing. Then:

$$f(A) = (f(x_0-\epsilon),f(x_0+\epsilon))$$

Therefore:

$$x \in A \implies f(x_0-\epsilon) < f(x) < f(x_0+\epsilon)$$

$$\implies f(x_0-\epsilon)-f(x_0) < y-f(x_0) < f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0)$$

Define $\delta = \min \{f(x_0)-f(x_0-\epsilon),f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0) \}$. Then:

$$|y-f(x_0)| < \delta \implies -\delta < y-f(x_0) < \delta$$

$$\implies f(x_0-\epsilon) < y < f(x_0+\epsilon)$$

$$\implies x_0-\epsilon < f^{-1}(y) < x_0 + \epsilon$$

$$\implies |f^{-1}(y)-x_0| < \epsilon$$

as was desired. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

I should also add that I used the fact that if $f$ is strictly, increasing, then $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing as well. To prove this, let $y_1,y_2 \in f(I)$ so that:

$$y_1 < y_2$$

Then, there exist $x_1,x_2 \in I$ so that $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_2) = y_2$. So:

$$f(x_1) < f(x_2)$$

and since $f$ is strictly increasing, $x_1 < x_2$. That is, $f^{-1}(y_1) < f^{-1}(y_2)$.

Comment: It has one small technical problem: if $I$ isn’t an **open** interval, you won’t be able to find such an $\epsilon$ if $x_0$ is an endpoint of the interval. The same argument clearly works with only very minor modification, but the possibility does at least have to be mentioned.

Comment: Oh okay, so all I need to do is to make that case super explicit? Let $x_0$ be an endpoint of $I$ so that $x_0 \in I$. We'll just do this for the left-endpoint and the argument is the same for the right endpoint. Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $[x_0,x+\epsilon)$. Since we are assuming that $f$ is strictly increasing WLOG, $f[x_0,x_0+\epsilon) = [f(x_0),f(x_0+\epsilon))$. In this instance, we define $\delta = f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0)$ and show the chain of implications as above. That would complete the argument, right?

Comment: Yes, that should do, though you probably should make it condition: **if** $I$ contains an endpoint, here’s how we handle it.

Comment: Alright thank you very much :D

Comment: You’re welcome!